# pushPayload isn't called

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to modify the behaviour of pushPayload in the RESTSerializer. However the function is never called.

```
pushPayload: function(store, payload) {
    console.log('pushPayload');
    payload = this.normalizePayload(payload);

    for (var prop in payload) {
      var typeName = this.typeForRoot(prop),
          type = store.modelFor(typeName),
          typeSerializer = store.serializerFor(type);

      /*jshint loopfunc:true*/
      var normalizedArray = map.call(Ember.makeArray(payload[prop]), function(hash) {
        return typeSerializer.normalize(type, hash, prop);
      }, this);

      store.pushMany(typeName, normalizedArray);
    }
},
normalizePayload: function(payload) {
    console.log('normalize');
  return payload;
},
```

This will output only:

> normalize

I really have no idea what's going on. I literraly copied from [the master](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L7) both methods. There is no typo and if normalizePayload is called pushPayload should be called also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`normalizePayload` is called from both `extractSingle` (`store.find('foo', 1);`), `store.extractArray` (`store.find('foo');`) and `pushPayload` (`store.pushPayload('foo', obj);`).

You need to actually call `pushPayload` on the store with the type of the serializer defined. Additionally be careful, map is defined earlier in the document:

```
var map = Ember.ArrayPolyfills.map;


App.FooSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  pushPayload: function(store, payload) {
    console.log('pushPayload');
    payload = this.normalizePayload(payload);

    for (var prop in payload) {
      var typeName = this.typeForRoot(prop),
          type = store.modelFor(typeName),
          typeSerializer = store.serializerFor(type);

      /*jshint loopfunc:true*/
      var normalizedArray = map.call(Ember.makeArray(payload[prop]), function(hash) {
        return typeSerializer.normalize(type, hash, prop);
      }, this);

      store.pushMany(typeName, normalizedArray);
    }
  },
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/730/edit

Comment: Thanks, I had a fundamental misunderstanding of pushPayload. I was using find() and somehow tought pushPayload was called after and then called normalizedPayload. So much to learn!